# My functions are not working in my django project

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm currently trying to return data in json or api view format with my following text fields (email, country and phone number), However I also have 2 validation functions to validate the value in the email and phone number fields which require the get() method and also using it to pass the text as a argument. I am not sure if the 2 validation functions are working or not as when I entered an invalid email, it is still accepted as a valid data. Please tell me what I am doing incorrectly and what changes should be made to my current code.

```
/* serializers.py */
import re
import phonenumbers
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import validation
from phonenumbers import carrier
from validate_email import validate_email


class validationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = validation
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        if not validate_email(email, check_mx=True, verify=True):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid email")
        return email

    def clean_phone_number(self):
        phone_number = self.cleaned_data.get("phone_number")
        clean_number = re.sub("[^0-9&^+]", "", phone_number)
        alpha_2 = self.cleaned_data.get("country")
        z = phonenumbers.parse(clean_number, "%s" % (alpha_2))
        if len(clean_number) > 15 or len(clean_number) < 3:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Number cannot be more than 15 or less than 3")
        if not phonenumbers.is_valid_number(z):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Number not correct format or non-existent")
        if carrier.name_for_number(z, "en") == '':
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Please enter a mobile number")
        return phonenumbers.format_number(
            z, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.E164)

/* models.py */
from django.db import models


class validation(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Comment: post the logic of `validate_email`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean is used with models and validate is used with serializers. So you have to use validate instead of clean. Format your code according to this example. Also, instead of self.cleaned_data use self.validated_data.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class EventSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    start = serializers.DateTimeField()
    finish = serializers.DateTimeField()

    def validate(self, data):
        """
        Check that start is before finish.
        """
        if data['start'] > data['finish']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("finish must occur after start")
        return data

    def validate_description(self, value):
        """
        Check that event is related to django.
        """
        if 'django' not in value.lower():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("It is not a django event")
        return data
```

In your case, you can rewrite the email validation like this.

```
def validate_email(self):
    email = self.validated_data.get("email")
    if not self.validate_email(email, check_mx=True, verify=True):
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid email")
    return email
```

Comment: So if I instead put the email and phone number fields in serializers.py and change the function names to start with validate_(something), it should work?

Comment: please see the updated solution. You can refer to this https://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation

Comment: Where then should I include my email and phonenumbers validation, it uses packages installed from PyPI? I need to get the value from what the user has entered and then validate.

Comment: I think that the validate_email method is not missing anything.

Comment: Do i have to register the serializer then since now it contains all the fields instead of models.py and does it mean i will no longer use models.py?

Comment: See, you have done everything right. You just have to change clean_email to validate_email and clean_phone_number to validate_phone_number. And use self.validated_data.get() to get the data from user. Please try once if you are not able to do it, I'll rewrite the whole code.

Comment: here is what ive written, and its not working :

class basicSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    emailplus = serializers.EmailField()
    country = serializers.CharField(max_length=2)
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

    def validate_emailplus(self):
        email = self.validated_data.get("email")
        if not validate_email(email, check_mx=True, verify=True):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid email")
        return email    /* if possible u can retype the whole code, thanks! */

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement does not return from the function, it should give a validationerror but after that it will still return the phone number.

Either you can return the function within the if statement, or you can use a structure as following:

```
if not phonenumbers.is_valid_number(z):
   raise serializers.ValidationError(
      "Number not correct format or non-existent")
elif carrier.name_for_number(z, "en") == '':
   raise serializers.ValidationError("Please enter a mobile number")
else:
   return phonenumbers.format_number(
         z, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.E164)
```

Comment: Ive rewritten the code according to the structure but when i add a new user on the admin site, the validation still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for [Validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/validators/), you can create a validation function and specify it in field under kwargs `validators=`

A part from link:

```
def validate_even(value):
    if value % 2 != 0:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('%(value)s is not an even number'),
            params={'value': value},
        )

-----------
even_field = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_even])
```